# Load list view when scrolling

Tags: wicket

I have a problem with an application that displays a list of documents using ListView:
The current design is the following:

- a ListView is created with nr of items = nrOfdocuments/50; the ListView is added to a scroller
- for each item of this ListView a new panel Batch is created (which represents a batch of documents - max 50 documents);
- this Batch class creates another ListView with maximum 50 items (each item representing a panel with a document's details - items are loaded only when the scroll reaches them)

For example: 
- for a total number of 1000 documents:  20 objects of type Batch will be created => 20 ListView objects will be created

The problem is that trying to load large amounts of documents (> 10000) will end with an Java out of memory exception. 
I want to improve this design, by keeping only one Batch loaded in memory once (so only max 50 documents) and to clear all the other ListView objects previously created which are not used anymore.
Do you have any ideas that can help me?

Comment: Not an answer but handling tens of thousands of objects shouldn't result in an OOM error, unless you have a lot of unnecessary data in your document object.

Answer (score 1):

You could only load 3 batches worth:

- One batch before the current batch
- The current batch
- The batch after the current batch

As the user scrolls up/down the list you could only load these three batches (as a user enters another batch reload the batches with the batch they entered as the new current batch).

To make the scrollbar display as if the list was full of old batches just insert dummy batches with empty documents e.g.

- Dummy batch 1
- Dummy batch 2
- One batch before the current batch
- The current batch
- The batch after the current batch

The only problem you would have is if the user searched up the list quickly before the ajax has time to reload the batches. This can't easily be solved, but it can be communicated to the user that the data is being loaded by having the dummy batches display a loading message for each document entry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish...

Do you want to replace the current 50 documents with a new set of 50 documents or do you want to keep the old ones for scrolling...

If the former, your approach doesn't seem like the first one I'd think of...

```
private class MyPanel extends Panel {
    private ListView lv;

public MyPanel(String id) {
    super(id);
    List list = new ArrayList();
    lv = new ListView("lv", list) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            //display the document
        }

    };

    add(lv);

    add(new AjaxButton("next", new Form("form")) {

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            //retrieve the next Batch
            List newList = new ArrayList();
            lv.setModelObject(newList);
            target.addComponent(MyPanel.this);
        }

    });
}

}
```

Something vaguely like this would come to my mind. You could 'scroll' back and forth like you did before.

Other than that, I'd think of a DataView instead of a ListView since it supports pagination out of the box.

As a last thought, if you just remove the references to your ListView without adding them (or any surrounding container since repeaters can't be added to AjaxRequestTargets), this would give the gc a chance to clean these objects but then you've got to take care of the null references when reloading...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly a wicket-related answer, more one that is making assumptions about your UI.

Have you considered using the [master-detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master-detail) UI pattern?

Instead of maintaining the entirety of the top level documents and their child documents at once, you would instead present the top level nodes in a list, and display only the child documents of the selected top-level node in a separate 'detail' panel.

In wicket, this is fairly straightforward, with something like an onClick event updating the model of the 'detail' panel (which pulls the child documents of the selected parent).

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/reaktor/oegyscroll